# On locus of points such that the product is constant.

Tags: geometry, locus

I tried to find locus of all points such that the product of distances from two focii is constant. I assumed that the vertex is at (+a,0), and the two focii are (+c,0) and (-c,0). I arrived at the following,

$ (\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2} -1)a^2 + 2(\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{a^2} +1)c^2 = 0 $

Is it correct. And Is it correct to find such locus? How do these look when plotted?

Comment: Substituting $(x,y)\to(a,0)$ into your formula yields $4c^2=0$, which requires $c=0$ and isn't what you intend. If you include your work, we may be able to show you where you went wrong. (By the way: the locus you seek is called an [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval).)

Answer (score 0):

We let a point $P$ a point of coords $(x,y)$. We have to have: $$((x-c)^2+y^2)((x+c)^2+y^2)=k, k\in R_0^+$$Substituing for $c$ we have: $$((x-4)^2+y^2)((x+4)^2+y^2)=k$$
This locus changes in function of $k$.